# Gradle: Sync task considers project up-to-date even though files are added to destination dir

Tags: gradle

I'm using this simple Gradle task:

```
task syncTask(type: Sync) {
    from "src/"
    into "dest/"
}
```

According to the [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html), I'm expecting that `src` is copied to `dest` and that any files not present in `src` are removed from `dest`. This basically works fine. However, if there are files added to `dest` after syncing, this is not recognized when the task runs again. The project is simply considered UP-TO-DATE and no action is taken.

Is it possible to configure the Sync task so that added files in the destination directory are detected and the task is run again?

```
> gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-11-19 08:20:02 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     7970ec3503b4f5767ee1c1c69f8b4186c4763e3d

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_25 (Oracle Corporation 23.7-b01)
OS:           Linux 3.2.0-53-generic amd64
```

**Edit 1:** Here are the steps to reproduce the behaviour:

```
$ mkdir src
$ touch src/a
$ mkdir dest
$ gradle syncTask
:syncTask

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.113 secs
$ ls dest/
a
```

So far, everything works as expected. Now, a file `b` is added to the `dest/` folder:

```
$ touch dest/b
$ ls dest/
a  b
$ gradle syncTask
:syncTask UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.024 secs
```

I would expect that `b` is removed from `dest/`. However, the Sync task doesn't seem to notice that its outputs have changed and thus doesn't run.

Comment: Alternative: fallback to ant sync, which hopefully does the right thing http://stackoverflow.com/a/28973518/469414

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it seems the Sync task is kinda broken, same in Gradle 1.10.
To solve that, I quickly hacked a custom task, just put it somewhere in your script.

```
class SyncDir extends DefaultTask {
    def inDir
    def outDir

    @TaskAction
    def run() {
        project.delete outDir
        project.copy { from inDir; into outDir }
    }

    def from(name) {
        inDir = new File(name)
    }

    def into(name) {
        outDir = new File(name)
    }
}
```

You can use it like the Sync task.

```
task toto (type: SyncDir) {
    from 'toto'
    into 'tata/toto'
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your work! Unfortunately, it seems that a file added to the destination folder still isn't recognized (the task is considered UP-TO-DATE). For my testcase, please see **Edit 1** in the original question.

Comment: Indeed, I had the same issue actually. What I did to fix it was to remove the InputFiles and OutputDirectory annotations. This removes the up-to-date check, but since it's broken this is good. I edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, now it works. Disabling the up-to-date check could probably also be done by setting `outputs.upToDateWhen {false}` in the built-in Sync task. I just hoped there was a way to keep it enabled...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the problem is related to this issue https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2270. A Sync task is considered up-to-date if all input files are present and up-to-date, ignoring any other files. It was reported in Gradle 1.0, and still does not work in Gradle 2.0.

As a work-around, I add following block to my Sync task

```
outputs.upToDateWhen {
    def Set<String> names = inputs.files.files.collect{ _ -> _.name }
    def Set<String> destDirContent = destinationDir.list().toList().toSet()
    def boolean good = names.containsAll(destDirContent)
    return good
}
```

In your case, the task should look like this.

```
task syncTask(type: Sync) {
    from "src/"
    into "dest/" 
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
        def Set<String> names = inputs.files.files.collect{ _ -> _.name }
        def Set<String> destDirContent = destinationDir.list().toList().toSet()
        def boolean good = names.containsAll(destDirContent)
        return good
    }
}
```

However it does not work (i.e. task is considered UP-TO-DATE) when source directory is empty, probably because some short-cut in Gradle code. It was not a problem for me, so I have not tried to find a better solution, just be aware of this case.

Comment: FWIW, here’s the same ticket in the current issue tracker: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1349